# How to execute a function decided by incoming parameter without if else

Tags: php, class

```
$arg = $_POST['argument'];
class a{
    public function sayYes(){
       echo 'Yes';
    }
    public function sayNo(){
       echo 'No';
    }
}
```

Here how do i execute sayYes if arg is 'yes' or execute sayNo if arg is 'no' without using if else asking it because if i had 30 functions it wouldn't be efficient

Comment: Why? If/else is _incredibly_ efficient. Have you actually tried and timed the if/else implementation? Because it sounds like you concluded it would be inefficient without actually verifying that.

Comment: i mean i want to make an array like $a = array('yes'=>a::sayYes(),'no'=>a::sayNo()); but it automatically executes both functions and foreach through it and if it exists within the array execute it

Comment: Again: why? Now you'll just be writing code in which it's a matter of time (and probably very litte time) before typo-related bugs break your code. So what are you _actually_ trying to do here, that you think requires the kind of code you're suggesting you think you need?

Comment: i just want to learn how would i do that. i searched through and couldn't find a way to not execute it within the array implementation. i'm not sure if that's the case but if i had a class with 200 functions would i need to do it by if-else one by one?

Comment: Then maybe someone else will help you - wanting to do what you're talking about is an anti-pattern that you should not be using in real code because it's a guaranteed source of bugs, and the indirection is absolutely less efficient than using proper well written conditional jumps to functions that can be verified to exist by your linter.

Comment: i can see if-else way being efficient but i've never seen if-else cases more than 10 of them. there should be a way to automate this

Comment: What is $arg then? It's impossible for us to answer if we don't know what $arg is and how that relates to the output you want. If $arg is "yes", and you expect output "yes" then just echo it. That is how much we can answer at the moment

Comment: well arg is supposed to be same to the function name so if arg's value is same to one of class' functions then it should execute, with if else if i had too much functions i'd need a lot of if-elses and i dont know why this is anti-pattern or the way i said in the first place with array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of syntax sugar, here are two ways in the spirit you are asking for.

1. Using an object

```php
$arg = 'yes';

class a {
    public static function sayYes() {
       echo 'Yes';
    }
    public static function sayNo() {
       echo 'No';
    }
}

a::{'say'.ucfirst($arg)}();
```

2. Using an array

```php
$arg = 'yes';

$funcs = [
    'yes' => function () {
        echo 'Yes';
    },
    'no' => function () {
        echo 'No';
    }
];

$funcs[$arg]();
```

Note: tested with PHP 7.2